# How do I apply the change of a Bool in one View to another View in Swift UI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am new to coding and I want to apply the change of a Bool in one View to another View.
How do I need to modify the code so it will work? Thank you in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AssignValuesToOtherStruct: View {
    
    @State private var rectangleIsShown = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if rectangleIsShown {
            BlueRectangle()
        }
    }
}

struct AssignValuesToOtherStruct_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AssignValuesToOtherStruct()
    }
}

struct BlueRectangle: View {
    
    @State private var rectangleIsShown = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {rectangleIsShown = false}) {
                Text("hide Rectangle")
            }
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: read about using `Binding` in SwiftUI.

Comment: This should help you out (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Binding property wrapper to create a 2 way connection, this way both views have access to it and both can modify it. Here is your modified code.

```
struct AssignValuesToOtherStruct: View {

    @State private var rectangleIsShown = true

    var body: some View {
        if rectangleIsShown {
          BlueRectangle(rectangleIsShown: $rectangleIsShown)
        }
    }
}

struct BlueRectangle: View {

  @Binding var rectangleIsShown: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {rectangleIsShown = false}) {
                Text("hide Rectangle")
            }
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```